# Kernel of an induced operator by a given Fredholm operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ and  $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T: X \rightarrow Y$ a Fredholm map between $X$ and $Y$. Take a complement $V \subset X$ to $\ker T$ and also take a complement $W \subset Y$ to the image $T(X)$. Then, one can define a map $T': X \rightarrow Y/W$ to be the composition of $T$ and the projection from $Y$ to $Y/W$. My question is the following: *What is the kernel of $T'$?* Is this equal to $\ker T$?  Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T'(x)=0$ is equivalent to $T(x)\in W$, since $T(x)\in Im(T), T(x)\in W\cap Im(T)=\{0\}$ i.e $T(x)=0$ i.e $x\in Ker T$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Tsemo, for the clear answer!